# "auto-tag" list entries during data entry in excel

Tags: excel, automation, tags

I want to make data entry easier for me by automating certain parts.
I always have one row with actual data (entry) and one with tags. the tags come from a list of fixed tags and dont repeat often, so the tag could always be added to each normal entry until it changes.

so instead of typing. "entry 1, tag 1, entry 2, tag 2" etc Id like to write only "tag 1, entry 1, entry 2, entry 3" etc.

i know excel cant "write" text only data to a cell if and I dont necessarily need a data pair each time. i only need the tag info so i can sum the different entries via the different tags later.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood properly but you can do :

1. Select tag cells (all of them)
2. Go to Search and Replace--> Find special
3. Select *blank cells*
4. This will select all blank cells in tag column. Now just type `=` and press up arrow on tke keyboard once (so the formula will be something like `=G4` in cell G5 as example if G5 is blank)
5. Accept the formula pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

[image]

Just a suggestion: after you do all this, select all cells and overwrite them with values. Just do Copy and paste as values in same selection, so the formulas will be replaced with values.

Comment: well yes, that technically works but data entry and tags are scanned via barcode scanner. so there isnt much interaction with the excel worksheet. or at least i want to keep working in excel to a minimum